# How do I save a string to a struct array member?

Tags: c

I am trying to save the string on array[0] to persons[0].name but I get this error: assignment to expression with array type. What should I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct person{
    char name[25];
};
int main(){
    struct person persons[10];
    int i=0;
    int array[10];
    char str[] ="This is a test";
    char * pch;

    printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
    pch = strtok (str," ");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
      array[i]=pch;
      pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
      i++;
    }
   //persons[0].name=array[0]; //error: assignment to expression with array type
   printf("persons.name: %s\n", persons[0].name);
   printf("array[0] = %s", array[0]);
}
```

Comment: `array[i] = pch;` is an error, pay attention to the compiler output

Comment: There are lots of compiler warnings, such as the fact that `strtok` is not defined (because you didn't include `<string.h>`) and that `array[i] = pch` is probably wrong (and I'm not even sure why that doesn't cause a compile error for MinGW). I don't think you understand what arrays are, so it might be a better idea to [pick up a good beginner's guide on C](//stackoverflow.com/a/562377/824425).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the whileloop. array[10] contains what is should contain.

Comment: How can that be? There *is* no valid `array[10]` in your code!

Comment: There **was** and **is** some wrong with that code. Your code here initially had the declaration `char array[10];`, and now it is `int array[10];`. `array` is an array of ten integers, but you're using it to store three `char*`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try `strcpy` instead of assigning the value with an `=`:

```
strcpy(persons[0].name, array[0])
```

Comment: The code can run but persons[0].name seems empty.

strcpy(&array[0],persons[0].name);

Comment: it did actually work. I just had to edit the syntax. strcpy(persons[0].name, array[0]);

Comment: Since `array[0]` is an `int`, the expression in the answer: `strcpy(persons[0].name, array[0])` cannot be right.  The function takes two `char *` arguments.

Comment: I think that's a typo made by the user. See his comment, he is saying that it's working